# Downloading multiple files using WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Our app needs to download files with the following requirements:

1. User can dynamically add or cancel downloads
2. Files are downloaded one at a time
3. Sometimes in background we need to schedule several file downloads
4. It would be nice to display a notification displaying download progress and a cancel button

We had all this implented in a foreground service that would maintain a queue of tasks and having an aidl interface with methods that allowed to enqueue new downloads or cancel active/enqueued.
Since Android 12 we can no longer start foreground service when the app is in background, so we can't reliably download files anymore in this situation (requirement #3)

As far as I can understand, the recommended way of implementing such task is using `WorkManager`, but I can't find a good way of doing it.

I consider two approaches, but both are far from perfect:

1. Every downloaded file is a separate Work. It's easy to cancel when needed and we only need to suply a file URL and that's it.
   But the downsides are: there's no way to enqueue several downloads at once (requirement #3), we need to wait for previous work to finish and then enqueue the next one.
   Using `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND` doesn't help here - our downloads are independent and if one is cancelled or fails, others should stay in the queue.
   Another annoying issue with this approach is that if we display a notification from our `ListenableWorker` via `startForeground()`, then for each file download it will be shown and hidded instead of just updating its contents for every new downloaded file.
2. Use a long running `ListenableWorker` that would download many files. But this requires somehow delivering `enqueue` and `cancel(fileUrl)` messages to the running worker instance (what we did previously using our service with the aidl/binder stuff). As far as I can see, the `WorkManager` API doesn't support anything like that. So the only thing we can do is to use some static vars to deliver those messages, which would work (if our worker works in the same process as the main app - hopefully, I can rely on that). But using statics in such a way is always kind of a code smell, I would avoid it if possible.

Are there any other possibilities to do this using `WorkManager`? Maybe I'm missing some part of the API?

Comment: Go with onetimerequest worker.

Comment: Your `Worker` works off of the queue while there are things to do, then exits. Your add/remove files logic updates the queue and, if needed, starts a `Worker`. "But using statics in such a way is always kind of a code smell, I would avoid it if possible" -- dependency inversion (DI) via Dagger/Hilt (or Koin, etc. on Kotlin) is available. Having a `Worker` get information from a DI singleton (e.g., a repository that manages your queue) is not unusual and fits with Google's architecture recommendations (for what that's worth).

Comment: @CommonsWare I don’t think hiding statics behind a DI framework would make things any better. An important thing about aidl for services is that a service can run in a separate process (`WorkManager` also can work like that). In my case everything is in one process (I hope) and I guess I have no other choice than using some sort of statics. However I would prefer the framework doing that communication for me if possible, it would definitely look more clean…

Comment: "I don’t think hiding statics behind a DI framework would make things any better" -- DI has been a fairly common practice for several years. Or, your queue could be something persistent (database, JSON file, etc.) instead of in memory (with the added bonus of then surviving things like process termination).

Comment: I totally do not understand 2 and 3. You want it one at a time in 2, but than it looks like you are saying that you need them in parallel and it is not working or what? Because you can schedule multiple downloads using chain works. And each will be executed after the previous one finishes. "There is no way to enqueue several downloads at once" is not true the way you say it. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work . Yes, you can.

Comment: @YavorMitev I don’t need them them to be executed in parallel, I need a queue where any task may fail or be cancelled independently. With chaining a task failure or cancellation has a downstream effect of cancellation of all the following tasks - I don’t want that.